# How can i Enable and Disable a button depending on whether or not i can copy?

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, richtextbox

I have been looking all over the place for this and I can't find anything, then I found this site and I hope I can get some help on this.

I have a RichTextBox called rtb1 and a Button called btn1.

I am making a simple Notepad and I need to know how I can disable a button depending on whether or not I can copy in my richTextBox1. What I want to know is how can I enable my button when I can copy but disable it when I can't copy?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in which situation you can't copy and need to disable the button

Comment: @user2266486 If you have nothing to copy, because nothing is selected.  Some programs choose to clear the clipboard in such cases, others find something to copy even with nothing selected, and some (apparently this one) just don't let you copy if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i can help you, i am working on an advanced NotePad and i have had to do just this

In your Undo button put in this code:

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtb1.Copy();
    }
```

and then put this code in your rtb1.TextChanged Event:

```
    if (rtb1.CanUndo == true)
    {
        btn1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (rtb1.CanUndo != true)
    {
        btn1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

That way if you can undo, you enable the undo button, but if you can't, disable it.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Your entire second snippet of code can just be written as `btn1.Enabled = rtb1.CanUndo`.  There's no reason to write it out like that.

Comment: This code worked for me and it helped jack nelson so i see no reason to change my whole code just because you don't like it. The answer you posted i tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to subscribe to the [`RichTextBox.SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged.aspx) event.  Enable your button if [`SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength.aspx) is greater than zero.

This can look like the following (add after `InitializeComponent` in your constructor, or in the Form's Load, etc):

```
rtb1.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    btn1.Enabled = rtb1.SelectionLength > 0;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "subscribe"? I am fairly new to programming

Comment: @JackNelson `SelectionChanged` is an *event* (just like `Button.Click`).  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx  This is very important to learn if you're going to use UI elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `SelectionChanged` event to update the textbox and use the `SelectionLength` property to know whether or not it should be enabled:

```
rtb1.SelectionChanged += (_, args) =>
{
    btn1.Enabled = rtb1.SelectionLength > 0;
};
```

Comment: I tried that and I get 6 errors.

Comment: @JackNelson Well, it compiles just fine for me, so you're going to need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me either.

Comment: @Dozer789 That's an equally unhelpful comment.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: +1 : No problems compiling for me...